# Puppeteer - Scroll infinite page don't work in headless mode

Tags: javascript, puppeteer, headless

I can not run the same code with headless on true.

I get this error: Navigation Timeout Exceeded: 30000ms exceeded

How can I fix this?

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: true})
  const page = await browser.newPage()
  await page.setRequestInterception(true)
  page.on('request', request => {
    if (request.resourceType() === 'image') {
      request.abort()
    } else {
      request.continue()
    }
  })
  await page.goto('http://amzn.eu/ebKNEqg')
  await scroll(page)

  let content = await page.content()
  let $ = cheerio.load(content)
  const whishlist = []
  $('h3.a-size-base a.a-link-normal').each((i, elem) => {
    whishlist[i] = $(elem).attr('href')
  })
  console.log(whishlist)
  await browser.close()
})()

async function scroll (page) {
  let i = 0
  while (await page.$('.wl-see-more') !== null) {
    i++
    // Scroll to bottom to load more
    await page.evaluate(_ => {
      window.scrollBy(0, window.innerHeight)
    })
    console.log('Loop #' + i)
  }
}
```

I also try to accelerate puppeteer by blocking the loading of images if you have other tips applicable here, I'm interested!

Comment: If I run your exact code, it seems to work. It loops 454 times, log the array and exit.

Comment: yes I just realized that it works well under linux. But I still have this problem under windows.

Comment: Works fine for me on Windows, even 3 years later. Voting to close as non-reproducible. As an aside, Puppeteer already parsed the DOM and has selectors so there's no need for Cheerio. Just do `page.$$eval('h3.a-size-base a.a-link-normal', els => els.map(e => e.getAttribute("href"))` and drop the extra work and dependency.